# building solr dictionary index

Tags: java, solr, spell-checking

I am using FileBasedDictionaryIndex. I have two files. I have set up searchcomponent in solrconfig with Standard request handler and also defined a new field type in schema with appropriate filters.

I want to know whether solr automatically builds index for the dictionary or do I need to write any code (I am using Java) for build Dictionary Index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SpellCheckComponent can be configured to automatically (re)build indices based on fields in Solr index when a commit or an optimize is done. See http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent

UPDATE: I edit this post after seeing the exchange about this topic on SOLR user list: the FileBasedDictionaryIndex needs a spellchecker.build command issued at least once (basically ignore the build / optimize trigger defined on solrconfig.xml)

Answer (score 0):

I entered this url to build spell check index.

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/select?   q=*:*&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.build=true&buildOnCommit=true
```

I got this result

```
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">0</int>
<lst name="params">
<str name="spellcheck">true</str>
<str name="q">*:*</str>
<str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
<str name="spellcheck.build">true</str>
</lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="0" start="0"/>
</response>
```

I am not getting why my index is not built.

Comment: This is a notmal query response. According to your configuration, your spell index should be built when a commit command is issued. Not sure what  doesd spellcheck.build=true because I never used that.

Comment: I found this url in various posts from different people used to build the index. Hence I tried it.

Please tell how should I go for it.

Comment: Did you try to issue a commit? No message in the log file?

Comment: Yes I did issue commit.

Comment: I can see these 3 files in spellchecker index.
_7.cfe
_7.cfs
_7.si

Every time I issue commit, first file names were like _1.<..>, than _5.<..> and now _7.<..>

Comment: if these are the index files than on enterring this url, numFound should not be 0 I suppose.

Comment: also, I saw earlier in my log, it showed an error that all Checkers should use same StringDistance.

Comment: Please advice me whatever suitable you can suggest

Answer (score 0):

```
My solrconfig is as below - 

<searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
<str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">text_spell</str>

<lst name="spellchecker">
   <str name="classname">solr.FileBasedSpellChecker</str>
   <str name="name">file1</str>
   <str name="sourceLocation">places.txt</str>

   <str name="characterEncoding">UTF-8</str>
   <str name="spellcheckIndexDir">./spellchecker1</str>
   <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
 </lst>

 <lst name="spellchecker">
   <str name="classname">solr.FileBasedSpellChecker</str>
   <str name="name">file2</str>

    <str name="sourceLocation">US.dic</str>
   <str name="characterEncoding">UTF-8</str>
   <str name="spellcheckIndexDir">./spellchecker2</str>
   <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
 </lst>

</searchComponent>
```

Please correct me.